# can not define and init a class member by Parentheses

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        A(): i(10) {}
        int i(5);   // error
//      int i = 5;     ok
//      int i = {5};   ok
//      int i{5};      ok
};

int main()
{
    int j(3); // ok
   return 0;
}
```

why can not use parentheses to init a member where it declared in class, but can use other form?

Answer (score 1):

It's simply not allowed to use direct-non-list-initialization syntax in the member specification of a class:

> member-declarator-list    -   similar to a init-declarator-list, but additionally allows bit-field declaration, pure-specifier, and virt-specifier (override or final) (since C++11), and **does not allow direct-non-list-initialization syntax**.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Member_specification